# Python: Valores de lista en una funcion a traves de variable asociada a radio button

Tags: python, tkinter

mi intencion es tener listas definidas y cuando se seleccione un radiobutton, pasar el valor de la lista para invocarla directamente. El problema es que me lo toma como un gran string y a veces el resultado termina siendo uno de los espacios. Como podria solucionarlo?

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

root.title("Simulador de tirada de dados")

varDados=StringVar()

dadosRegular=["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
dadosEspecial=["-3","1","3","5","5","8"]

def tirarDado():
    print(varDados.get())
    print("Resultado de la tirada es: ", random.choice(varDados.get()) )


frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()

Label(frame, text="Elige deado a Lanzar", width=50).pack()

Radiobutton(frame, text="Regular", variable=varDados, value=dadosRegular, command=tirarDado).pack()
Radiobutton(frame, text="Especial", variable=varDados, value=dadosEspecial, command=tirarDado).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.title("Simulador de tirada de dados")

dadosRegular = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
dadosEspecial = ["-3", "1", "3", "5", "5", "8"]


def tirarDado(dado):
    i = random.randint(0, len(dado) - 1)
    print("Resultado de la tirada es: ", dado[i])


frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

Label(frame, text="Elige deado a Lanzar", width=50).pack()

Radiobutton(frame, text="Regular", command=lambda: tirarDado(dadosRegular)).pack()
Radiobutton(frame, text="Especial", command=lambda: tirarDado(dadosEspecial)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Se asigna una función ***lambda*** (anónima) al parámetro `command` en cada objeto *Radiobutton* y cada función *lambda* llama a la función `tirarDado` con una de la listas como valor de entrada.

En `tirarDado` se genera un número entero al azar entre 0 y el número de elementos de la lista `dado` menos 1. Después, se accede al elemento de `dado` cuyo índice es el número aleatorio que hemos generado.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Jose! Me sirvió mucho tu aporte y es mucho mas eficiente que la forma que yo había encontrado por mi cuenta, con muchas más lineas de codigo jejeje

Comment: De nada, me alegro de haber ayudado.